# reWrite wp-content url to point on my cdn

Tags: functions, url-rewriting, urls, wp-config, cdn

I want to serve **wp-content** from my digitalocean Spaces CDN. I want to do this without a plugin. In the wp-admin/options.php the only URL I can change is upload_url_path.

Comment: Why without a plugin? There are very good ones that do exactly this.

Comment: I avoid using plugins if I can manually fix something.